# Changing the MarketingCloudConfig later in the apps lifecycle

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

so our problem is that we don't have the required information for initializing the SDK in the `Application`'s `onCreate` since we let the user change the country and other information at a later point. So for example for different countries the MID would probably change.

Would it be possible to initialize the SDK later in the lifecycle with the `Application`'s `Context` or would it be possible to change the `MarketingCloudConfig` at a later point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 100% supported that you can change the config and re-initialize the SDKs and many customers do so effectively.  As for whether or not you should/should not initialize the SDK in your application's onCreate(): *this is not optional* and the features of the SDK will not work unless you do so.  Why?  Because, for instance, push messages are a manifest level intent filter in Android (and handled by the OS for iOS) which will launch your application and expect the SDK to do work.  If you have not initialized the SDK in your application's Application#onCreate() then the SDK will simply error out and your message will be suppressed.

The way customers have worked around this is to either register the user in a parent BU and set the child (longterm?) BU once that information is known.  You can even migrate the data from the original BU to the child BU at runtime, but be sure to `disablePush()` for the BU you're moving from or the user might still see messages from the original BU (ref. https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/f7e04c905bd97656496b1bc0a8ec7c30).

So, the recommendation is to dynamically create the config and store it in local storage.  If it's null, don't init the SDK.  If you have a config available init the SDK, but do so in your application's Application#onCreate().